# MATLAB Mupad Issues

Tags: matlab, mupad

I am having issues with the MuPad 3d graphic display in MATLAB.  When I got to click in the window to control the display it looks like this with the gray borders around it.

[image]

If anyone could show me how to change this so that the grey borders are gone that would be great!

Comment: This looks like a bug, or some software instalation problem

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this in Matlab R2015b on OS X. I assume you've tried restarting Matlab and relaunching MuPAD?

Comment: Yes I have tried restarting both applications, do you think I should go for a re installation?